# How to write a variable/parameter to stdout?

Tags: azure-bicep

I'm trying to debug my first [Bicep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/overview) template.

How can I just write a variable or parameter value to standard output?

Something like:

```
var hello = 'hello world!'
write-host(hello)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best is to use module outputs which you can read from Portal. Module deployments are separate deployments visible in the "Deployments" section of resource group / subscription / etc. Even if the top-level deployment will fail, outputs from modules inside that were successful can be read, alongside parameters they took.

Remember, that bicep is a declarative language, not imperative, so the file is not being processed sequentially.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a shot as a work-around - though I won't mark it as accepted, as it's not really what I was looking for...  while I'm enjoying most things about Bicep so far, this strikes me as quite a severe limitation:  enabling users to see the evaluated result of an expression at runtime (easily and without jumping through hoops) should be a thing.

Comment: place an issue on the bicep github. as for the answer - it's simple - you cannot do that now. I've provided you a best workaround.

Comment: I agree with Nathan.

Comment: I put in a feature request https://github.com/Azure/bicep/issues/7924

Answer (score 3):

I created some simple `hello world` type templates early on in Bicep's history for this type of question https://github.com/Azure/bicep/tree/main/src/Bicep.Core.Samples/Files/user_submitted/000/01-hello-world .

The've been moved around and are harder to find, but still helpful.